# count duplicate value in recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

how to count the duplicate values in string/array by recursion, well i know how to find the duplicate and unique by the loop with the object, but in this case, i tried to recursion it to learn my logic, 
here is what i tried

```js
function duplicate(word) {
  let [obj, arr, count ] = [{},[],0]
  for (i of word) {
    obj[i] = (obj[i] || 0) + 1

    if (obj[i] == 2) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
  }

  // console.log(arr);
  let words = [...word];
  words = [...new Set(words)];
  // // return word
  if (words.length === 0) {
    return count
  } else if (arr.includes(words[0])) {
    count++
  }
    return count + duplicate(words.slice(1))

}


console.log(duplicate('xmikemk')) // 2
```

i tried to create object fist and pust  to newArr if the values found 2 times,
then i tried to SET the word in again below to just show the unique value, then i recursions it, when i console log it, the slice method on that  below to recursion and is not working, that is why the ouput i got here is 0, what is wrong with my code ? am I wrong with that condition??

that variable word has = `('xmikemk') which has 2 duplicate words, m and k , so the output i want is`2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could spread the given string and take only the first character for counting, by taking another parameter for handing over the last counted values.

If no more spreadable items, the count is made and returned. Otherwise go on with the recursive call.

```js
function duplicate([w, ...rest], counter = {}) {
    counter[w] = (counter[w] || 0) + 1;
    if (!rest.length) {
        return Object.values(counter).reduce((s, c) => s + (c > 1), 0);
    }
    return duplicate(rest, counter);
}

console.log(duplicate('xmikemk')) // 2
```

Comment: cant we just use one parameter and not edit the parameter??

Comment: how do you like to count the values?

Comment: like what i did loop it then recursion in below:D, is that impossible?

Comment: you have no real recursion, because you take all characters (instead of words) and just count the actual (which is a bit of cheating, in terms of a recursive solution.)

Comment: hmm  ok i  will see, why the `rest` variable the slices ??

Comment: it is just a short form of getting the first item and all other items.

Comment: i just know that , and it is cool, it seems like that variable slice themself wihtout call to slice it, i console log it

Answer (score 0):

You are making this more complicated than it is. Just create an internal accumulator method to populate a map and increment the frequency.

```js
function duplicate(word) {
  return duplicateInternal(word, {});
}

function duplicateInternal(word, mapping) {
  if (word == null || word.length === 0) {
    return mapping;
  }
  var c = word.charAt(0);
  mapping[c] = (mapping[c] || 0) + 1;
  return duplicateInternal(word.substr(1), mapping);
}

var mapping = duplicate('xmikemk');
var frequency = Object.keys(mapping)
  .map(key => [key, mapping[key]])
  .sort((a, b) => {
    let diff = -1 * (a[1] - b[1]);
    return diff === 0 ? a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) : diff;
  });

console.log(frequency.map(x => x.join(' x')).join('\n'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: i just want to learn how to recursion :D. i appreciated with your answer, it is useful to learn with different answer from masters here :D